# Django running long sql process in background

Tags: django

I have a web page where I need to run a long sql process (up to 20 mins or so) when the user clicks on a certain button. The script runs, but the user is then unable to continue browsing the rest of the website.

I would like to have it so that when the button is clicked, it goes into a queue that runs in the background.

I have looked inth django-background-tasks, but the problem is that it does not seem to be possible to start the queued tasks without running `python manage.py process_tasks`.

I have heard of Celery, but I am using a Windows system and it does not seem to be suitable.

I am new to django and website infrastructures, and am not sure if this is feasible. I have also seen in older response that the threading package can work to do this, but I am unsure if it is outdated.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with running process_tasks.

Comment: To add to the comment above - with most common background job frameworks you will need to start a separate process that runs alongside your regular webserver. You do not need to call `python manage.py process_tasks` each time you want a task to be run, you need to call it once and leave that process running alongside your webserver process.

Comment: I use Celery and run Windows 10. Complete doable. I also use Docker, which makes cross-platform development easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use create_task provided by Asyncio that can run a background task for you without blocking the view for clients.

Python 3.7+

[Asyncio create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#id4)

Disclaimer: I'm not so sure if myfunc() needs to be async unless you are performing an async worthwhile task.

You could also have a while loop in myfunc() for periodic repeated operations.

```
import asyncio

async def myfunc():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Hi, after 5 seconds.")

task = asyncio.create_task(myfunc(), )
```